# What about this eigenvalue problem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the eigenvalue problem
$$\begin{cases}
u^{\prime\prime} =\lambda u\\
u(0)=u(T)=0
\end{cases}.$$

Again during the math class, the professor said that the eigenvalues of this problem are well known and are related to $\frac{\pi}{T}$ or something like that.

Could someone please give me a reference about that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sines and cosines? SHM?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I tought about something like sine and cosine, but I am looking for the correct expression of eigenvalues (he said that there is a sort of formula related to $\pi$ and $T$).

Comment: This is discussed for example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of $\lambda<0$, $$u=A\cos(\sqrt{|\lambda|} x) + B\sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x).$$ $u(0)=0$ implies $A=0$ so
$$u=B\sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x)$$
and therefore $u(T)=0$ implies
$$B\sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}T)=0$$
either $B=0$ in which case $u(x)=0$ or
$$\sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}T)=0$$
implying that $\sqrt{|\lambda|}T = n\pi$ so $\lambda = -\frac{n^2\pi^2}{T^2}$ and
$$u(x) = B\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{T}x\right)$$

If $\lambda=0$, then $u=Ax+B$ so that $u=0$ is the only solution.

If $\lambda>0$, then
$$u=Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} + Be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$
and again
$$u(0)= A + B =0 \\
u(T) = Ae^{\sqrt{\lambda}T} + Be^{-\sqrt{\lambda}T}=0$$
Since
$$ \begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
  e^{\sqrt{\lambda}T} & e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}T}
\end{vmatrix} = 0 $$ only when $T=0$, $A,B=0$.

Comment: Doge Chan, thank you for the answer. So what is the solution in the case $\lambda>0$? It is $0$? I am interested in the sequence of eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes. $u=0$ in that case since the form of the solution is listed above.

Comment: Keep in mind that eigenvalues are only for non-zero functions so the negative case is the only case of eigenvalues.